# Why water vapor condenses on glass?

Tags: thermodynamics, evaporation, heat-conduction

I've read an answer to this question that stated glass was colder than air, causing this transfer of energy from the vapor to the glass, creating this condensation. But why is the glass colder than air? Don't all things reach an equilibrium temperature when left in a room?

Could it be that the glass is a good conductor of heat, therefore conducting this heat away from the surrounding water vapor, causing condensation?

Could someone please explain why water vapor condenses on glass in detail as well as why water vapor condenses on the mirror when having a hot shower?

Comment: Please provide a link to the question/answer you mention, and preferably quote the important sections of that material.    As to your last question - rather obviously hot water in the shower is hotter than the walls and mirror.

Answer (score 1):

For condensed water to accumulate on a surface requires that the surface be a little cooler than the air/vapor mixture next to it. So in your bathroom, the steamy air coming from the shower is a little warmer than the glass mirror, and since the air is probably close to saturation at that temperature, water is going to condense on the mirror surface.

If it's colder outdoors than inside your bathroom, water will condense on the inside of your bathroom window for the same reason.